# How to select widget by id?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to add many widgets on python code like this,

```
for item in parsed_result:
    time.sleep(0.01)
    btn = Button(text=item['id'], size_hint=(.5, None), height=32,
                 on_release=self.click_device_id)
    txt = TextInput(id=item['id'], text='hello', size_hint=(.5, None),
                    height=32)
    add_widget_target.add_widget(btn)
    add_widget_target.add_widget(txt)

def click_device_id(self, myself):
    # I want print TextInput.text on same level.
    self.go_next_screen()
```

The problem is I couldn't add a txt as a btn on_release parameter. So, I need they way how to select txt widget to print text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lambda like below.

```
for item in parsed_result:
    time.sleep(0.01)
    txt = TextInput(id=item['id'], size_hint=(.5, None), height=32, text='IMSI', multiline=False)
    btn = Button(text=item['id'], size_hint=(.5, None), height=32,
                     on_release=lambda ti=txt: self.click_device_id(ti.text, txt.text))
    add_widget_target.add_widget(btn)
    add_widget_target.add_widget(txt)

def click_device_id(self, button_text, txt_text):
    print button_text, txt_text
    self.go_next_screen()
```